# Hibernate criteria.list() returns empty list when using Restrictions.not

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Spring with JPA 2.0 and Hibernate 4.2.19.Final and I am trying to build a dynamic query which has simple predicates generated from the `Restrictions` class like method.
`Restrictions.like("attributes.value" + value.getKey() , value.getValue());`. My entity is stored in a sparse table where the number of the column relates to an attribute description.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_ENTITIES")
public class Entity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  @Embedded
  Attributes attributes;
}

@Embeddable
public class Attributes{

  /** Attribute 1. */
  @Embedded
  @Column(name = "value_1")
  private String attribute1;

         *

  /** Attribute N. */
  @Embedded
  @Column(name = "value_N")
  private String attributeN;
}
```

There are complex predicates such as AND, OR, NOT predicates which are obtained by nesting the simple predicate described above.

Everything seems to work well when I am using AND and OR predicates but with more complex expressions which involves a NOT, such as for example:

```
((attribute1=% OR attribute2=%) AND attribute3=%) AND NOT attribute4=%
```

the Criteria.list() method returns empty list when there are entities in the DB satisfying the criteria.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the criterion:

```
Restrictions.not(Restrictions.like("attributes.value" + value.getKey(), value.getValue()));
```

returns **`false`** if the value in the table is **`null`**.

Fixed this by modifying my simple criterion like this:

```
Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNotNull("attributes.value" + value.getKey()),
     Restrictions.like("attributes.value" + value.getKey(), value.getValue()));
```